# session not working in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.5

When I use this code, it will echoes the date after I comment on the first line and click on the route again, then it will not respond.

```
Session::put('pickup_date',$_GET['pickup_date']);
echo Session::get('pickup_date');

//Session::put('pickup_date',$_GET['pickup_date']);
echo Session::get('pickup_date');
```

Comment: Could that be because the first time you have a GET param in your url and the second time you don't? E.g. is there ?pickup_date=16-11-2017 or something similar in your URL.

Comment: once we put in session it was there untin i flush it

Comment: What I expect to happen is that the session gets cleared when you refresh it and you don't have a GET param set any longer. I can't reproduce it in Laravel 5.5 so I do not think it's a bug. :-)

Comment: there is one code of two lines code first time uper code run and second time is same code but first line commented